# High voltage led detector

Tags: led, control, detector, indicator

I need a circuit to indicate if the DC voltage across two points is exceeded a certain High value (**350 V**) by using LED as an indicator. For example if the voltage is 355 V then the LED will light,but if the voltage is 345 the LED won't light. thank you for helping me.
your sincerely Moad Nassar

Comment: I would recommend a resistive voltage divider with the ratio 1:100 and then a comparator with a 3,5 V reference. The output of the comparator drives the LED through a current limiting resistor. The comparator needs its own supply voltage.

Comment: and adding to Uwe's excellent suggestion you might want to add a bistable (as a memory) to indicate that  the voltage **had been** temporarily exceeded.

Comment: Thank u Uwe and JIm  i'll try it.

Comment: However, be aware that, in reducing the voltage, you also reduce the range of voltage near the trigger point, and making a comparator which will reliably detect very small voltage differences can be a challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a simple *comparator*.  However, neither LEDs nor comparators run at 350 V.  You therefore need to divide down the input voltage to something in the range of what a comparator can handle.

Let's say you use a 9 V battery to power your detector.  You can make a 3.3 V reference from the 9 V battery with a single cheap chip and use that as the threshold voltage.

A simple *resistor divider* can scale 350 V down to 3.3 V.  The top resistor needs to ideally be 105.1 times the bottom.  If you make the top 10 MΩ, for example, then the bottom resistor must be 9.52 kΩ.

Many comparators are available with open collector outputs.  Arrange the output to go low when input voltage is above the threshold.  Connect the LED in series with a resistor between the 9 V battery and the comparator output.  Let's say you are using a red LED and want to run it at 20 mA.  That will drop about 1.8 V, leaving up to 7.2 V across the resistor.  By Ohm's law, the resistor should be (7.2 V)/(20 mA) = 360 Ω.  Just be safe, I'd use the next higher common value of 390 Ω.